# Meaning of star icon overlay in Visual Studio 2022's Autos Window

Tags: visual-studio

What is the meaning of the star icon overlay that appears in Visual Studio 2022's [Autos Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/autos-and-locals-windows?view=vs-2022)? (Could not find anything even remotely related :-(  In fact, what do the icons mean? I guess they are IntelliSense icons.)

[image: Icons with star overaly in Autos Window]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/class-view-and-object-browser-icons?view=vs-2022#signal-icons

Comment: @HansPassant It seems that's the answer. It helped. Please post it as an answer so that I can upvote and choose! :)